# Search in Github

Tags: javascript, docker, github

Im trying to search in all repo with nodejs in the title and a docker-compose.yml file in it, so i tried to do : `nodejs filename:docker-compose.yml` but it didn't work.

`nodejs language:javascript filename:docker-compose` -> return javascript repo but they don't have any docker-compose file in it.

Anyone know how to do it correctly ?

Comment: `repo:nodejs/node filename:docker-compose.yml`. It doesn't return anything, though.

Comment: I found some repo in github in javascript (nodejs) with docker-compose file, I guess this is not the right method to search ?

Comment: the nodejs repository is `nodejs/node`, and has no `docker-compose.yml` (I don't think). Are you trying to find any fork of nodejs or any repo called nodejs with any owner?

Comment: i'm trying to find a nodejs repo with a docker-compose file, I'm just looking other project to see what they are doing with docker and multicontainer

Comment: Your best bet is `filename:docker-compose.yml language:JavaScript` then. GitHub can't specifically identify javascript repositories as Node.js. Also, you can "build" GitHub search queries at https://github.com/search/advanced

Comment: Ok thank you for your time i will try to do some queries:)